# SystemEvents event in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

Does Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents works under .NET Core/6? If not, how can I attach and detect windows session switching?

I am migrating an app from .NET Framework to .NET 6 and need to react on session switch (login/logoff).

Comment: Yes, it works.  Ensure that the .csproj file contains `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and the `TargetFramework` is net6.0-windows.  You can't run your program on a Unix machine.

Comment: Is this `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` really needed? This app is not Windows Forms or WPF, but a console application

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Don't see anything in common with XY here.. I am asking about your proposed solution. Anyway, it isn't working with and without it.